# What is the best way to create a file when a record in the database changes?

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a program where i can change a field. After changing it the database, which is connected with the program, updates immediatly. So a record is changed in the database.

Now I want, in SQL Server Management Studio, after the change that automatically a .txt file will be created or changed.

I know you can make triggers and stored procedures. Which is the best option? Or is there another option who's better?
And No I can't do it with the program where I changed the field.

Comment: What's the purpose of the .txt file?  There may be a more sensible way to accomplish your goal if we know some more details.

Comment: I find it difficult to explain. So I will try it.

Comment: I have two databases on different networks. One database, which has more than 800 tables, changes everytime if someone change a field in the program. If there is a change in a certain table I want to get that change and pass it on to a other database on a different network automatically.

Comment: When you say "change in a certain table", are you talking about a DML statement (UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT)?

Comment: I mean if there is an UPDATE

Comment: Maybe it is good to say that the database will never do a Rollback

Comment: So when data is updated in DatabaseA on ServerA, you want to synchronize that data with DatabaseB on ServerB.  Am I close?

Comment: Yes exactly. In Database B I have a field: clientnumber. This field has Database A too (the one with 800 tables). Database A has also an field named: amount. This field will change everytime when a user change it in the program. (I can't do anything with this program, I only can work in the Database). When the field is changed in Database A, Database B must get automatically the same change. So field: amount, in Database B must be updated.

Comment: My first thought was to use a trigger that updates DatabaseB on ServerB via a linked server connection.  However, you mentioned the two Sql Servers are on "different networks".  Does that mean each server is on a different domain?

Comment: Yes they are on different domains too!